# Symfony3 Forms–obtain Form with choices, default data etc. as JSON

Tags: json, forms, rest, symfony

I have a Symfony3 Application setup and would like to rebuild the frontend based on React now.

One of the Entities is `User` and each of them can have one or more `Groups` so in the HTML form a list of Checkboxes appears, so the admin can select the groups attached to a User.

In `UserType.php` this looks like that:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{   
    $builder
        ->add('username',   TextType::class)
        ->add('password',   TextType::class)
        ->add('email',      EmailType::class)
        ->add('groups',     EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Group::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'expanded'      => true,
            'multiple'      => true//,
            //'data'            => $builder->getData()->getGroups()

        ]);
}
```

To render the Form using React, it would be extremely handy to get a JSON response which could look like that:

```
{
  "user": {
    …
    "groups": [<gid 1>, …]
    "groups_available": [
      {
        "id": <gid 1>,
        "name": …
      },
      …
    ]
  }
}
```

So that the `groups` array contains all the ids of the groups, the user is attached to and `groups_available` a list of all available groups.

Right now I am using `FOSRestBundle` and in the Controller it looks like that:

```
public function getUserformAction($id=null)
{
    //if the id is null, create a new user
    //else get the existing one
    …

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $view = $form->createView();
    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you should try the following code:

```
 ->add('groups', EntityType::class, array(
    //if Group is in AppBundle or use the required Bundle name
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Group',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                                     ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC')
                             },
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => true,
                ));
```

You can also get a reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627526/put-data-form-database-into-checkbox-symfony-3/40633348#40633348)

Comment: The is working, that is not the issue. I want to replace the html form by one created with react on the frontend, therefore I need JSON data, which describes the form with all possible selections.

Answer (score 0):

After digging in the source and with the help of the debugger I could manage to do it in a more less robust and generic way like so:

```
protected function getFormStructure(Form $form)
{
  return $this->iterateFormview($form->createView(), []);
}

private function iterateFormview(FormView $view, array $result)
{
  foreach($view as $child) {
    $vars = $child->vars;
    $data = ['value' => $vars['value']];

    if(isset($vars['choices'])) {
      $data['choices'] = [];

      foreach ($vars['choices'] as $choice) {
        array_push($data['choices'], [
          'label' => $choice->label,
          'value' => $choice->value]);
      }
    }

    $result[$vars['full_name']] = $data;

    if(count($child) > 0) {
      $result = $this->iterateFormview($child, $result);
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Result (as json):

```
{
  …
  "user[groups]":
  {
    "value": "",
    "choices":  [
      {
        "value": 100,
        "label": "the name"
      },
      …
    ] 
  }
}
```

I guess this routine needs to be extended if I need to support more types… But for now this will do it.